# JSF page does not properly set object attributes

Tags: jsf, cdi

Simple question from a beginner at JSF:

I have very simple JSF form:

```
<h:form>
<p>#{messages.loginTextfieldUsername}</p>
<h:inputText value="#{userServiceImpl.user.name}" />

<p>#{messages.loginTextfieldPassword}</p>
<h:inputSecret value="#{userServiceImpl.user.password}" />

<h:commandButton value="#{messages.loginButtonLogin}" action="#{userServiceImpl.authenticateUser}" />
</h:form>
```

The userServiceImpl class is:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private UserSession userSession;
private User user;

@Inject
public UserServiceImpl(UserSession userSession) {
    this.userSession = userSession;
}

@PostConstruct
public void prepareService() {
    user = new User();
}

@Override
public View authenticateUser() {
    userSession.setLoggedUser(user);
    return View.MAIN;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

My goal is pretty simple: when the user hits the login button, I want to authenticate the user.

The problem is: 
When the authenticate method is called, the User attributes are null. I debugged the application and the getUser method is called and the values are properly set, but at some point (which I did not find [yet]) before the authenticateUser is called the User attributes are set to null...

I'm aware that this is a pretty basic question... but are you able to point out where my mistake is?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using @PostConstruct method to create new User, why don't you have it initialized directly. Also user field is not there in code you posted, might have forgotten.

Comment: Sorry, I did miss the User class code. I don't have the code here (I'm at work at this very moment) - but the class is a POJO: has two attributes (name and password) and four method: setName, getName, setPassword and getPassword. 
I use @PostConstruct due to personal taste - no other reason. I had tried to move the user = new User(); to the constructor, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: This problem suggests that a new `UserServiceImpl` instance is been constructed everytime the EL expression is evaluated. You can confim it by checking the class' hashcode in the debugger if it is different during the setter method call and the action method call. I can explain this problem when you're using `@ManagedBean`, but you're here using CDI `@Inject` which *defaults* to request scope already, so I can't explain it. To be sure, what package did you import the `@RequestScoped` from? The `javax.enterprise.context`, right?

Comment: Hi - yeah, I was importing from javax.faces.bean - another silly mistake. It's working now - thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677926/how-to-declare-many-jsf-managed-beans-at-once), you seem to have experimented with `<managed-bean-scope>` of `none` in `faces-config.xml` for some reason. The problem symptoms matches exactly when using `@ManagedBean @NoneScoped`.  You seem to have configured this bean in `faces-config.xml` as well on a `none` scope which totally explains this problem. With the `none` scope, a brand new bean instance is been created everytime when `#{userServiceImpl}` is been evaluated in EL. Your form submit has thus effectively created 3 beans: one where the user name is set, another one where user password is set and another one where action is invoked.

You need to **remove** the managed bean configuration from `faces-config.xml`. You should not use it when you intend to use `@Inject` (or `@ManagedBean`). The `faces-config.xml` way of configuring beans is a leftover from old JSF 1.x ages when annotations weren't available. As of JSF 2.x it would only *override* any bean management annotations.